# Save images as 60x60 pixels in r

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
filePaths <- filePathFunction(files)
image(readPNG(filePaths[1]), useRaster=TRUE, axes=FALSE)

image_resize(image_read(filePaths[1]), "60x60!")
plot(f)
png("myplot.png")
dev.off()
```

Its supposed to use readPNG to collect a raster array of the PNG image and what I want to do is to change all the images from size 200x200 to size 60x60 then save them. I can't do that with dev.off() because r resizes the background as well as the image on it.

Comment: the r viewer manages to get a picture of 60x60 pixels which I can save but how do I automate this?